# Find and prove the smallest $a$ which satisfies the following systems of equations: $x+y=a$ and $x^y=n$ for a given $n$.

Tags: combinatorics, logarithms, systems-of-equations

**Additional Requirements:** $x$ and $y$ must be natural numbers

**Motivation:** This question spawned from my
desire to be able to press the fewest buttons with enough combinations to access every point in a 256x256(65565 total points) grid for a personal project. The posited systems of equations were my best model of the situation, but I cannot figure out a way to prove or solve the posited systems of equations.

**Specific Case:** n = 65536

**My attempt**

My first thought was to try to solve the systems of equations with substitution, but I got stuck.

$x + y = a$
$x^y = 65536$

$y = x - a$

$x^{x-a} = 65536$

$\log_x(65536) = a - x$

I don't know how to(or if it's possible) solve for x here.

**Note:** Definitely open to a different mathematical model, especially if the one I generated proves unsolvable or highly impractical to solve. I don't think there's any more context I could provide to use in the generation of a new model. However, if you have a clarifying question or a specific question about the context of the problem, I'd be happy to add my answer to your question as an edit to the original post

Comment: Must $x, y$ be integers?

Comment: "$y=x−a$" $\;-\;$ That should be $y=a-x$ instead.

Comment: @Calvin Lin yes those need to be natural numbers, I'll change that now

Comment: $x^y=2^{16}$ only has 3 solutions, $2^{16},\,4^8$ and $16^4$, right?

Comment: @ContraKinta 5 solutions in natural numbers: $2^{16}, 4^8, 16^4, 256^2, 65536^1$.

Comment: Sorry, assumed symmetric limit on a. But still a= 4+8=12 is the answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesn't make sense to me. The difficulty is just the prime factorization of $n$? Then it is just a few (depending on the size of $n$)  steps up to a. Use the symmetric limit on $a$ to make sure the value is indeed the min.

Comment: @ContraKinta I have no idea what any of that means, but I'll look up some of those terms. I wouldn't be surprised if this is already a solved problem and I just don't know the answer.